# A question in real analysis 2

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is differentiable infinitely many times continuously, and let $P(x)$ be an polynomial of odd degree for which for every differential $f^{(n)}$ of $f$, $|f^{(n)}(x)| \leq |P(x)|$, and the same for the function itself.

I must prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, I can see why exists a point for which it gets zero, since the polynomial has a root. But how do I prove that the function is zero everywhere?

Comment: Hi Uri, I think it's time you started learning MathJax. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference You can have a look at how I've edited your question (basically, putting `$` signs around mathematical expressions is a decent place to start).

Comment: There is no such function $f$, including the $0$ function. An odd degree polynomial must tend to $-\infty$ as $x \to \infty$ or $x \to -\infty$. In particular, $P(x) < 0$ for certain values of $x$. For such values, we have $0 \le |f^{(n)}(x)| \le P(x) < 0$, which cannot be satisfied.

Comment: Corrected to |P(x)|. A typo of course.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_0$ be a zero of $P$, so that $f^{(n)}(x_0) = 0$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

In order to prove that $f\equiv 0$ it is enough to show that $f$ is analytic.
Namely, this can be easily checked since, on every compact interval $[x_0-a, x_0+a]$, one has
$$
|f^{(n)} (x)| \leq M \qquad \forall x\in [x_0-a, x_0+a],\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N},
$$
where $M := \max_{[x_0-a, x_0+a]} |P|$.